# Stack two columns in a DataFrame, repeat others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with a structure like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( [
            [ 'foo1', 'a', 'z', 'bar1', 1, 4 ],
            [ 'foo2', 'b', 'y', 'bar2', 2, 5 ],
            [ 'foo3', 'c', 'x', 'bar3', 3, 6 ]
        ] )
df.columns = [ 'foo', 'let1', 'let2', 'bar', 'num1', 'num2' ]
print( df )
```

---

```
    foo let1 let2   bar  num1  num2
0  foo1    a    z  bar1     1     4
1  foo2    b    y  bar2     2     5
2  foo3    c    x  bar3     3     6
```

I want to stack the columns `let1` and `let2`, and add a label telling where they came from. The same for `num1` and `num2`. In the end, I would like to achieve this:

```
    foo   let letval   bar   num  numval
0  foo1  let1      a  bar1  num1       1
1  foo2  let1      b  bar2  num1       2
2  foo3  let1      c  bar3  num1       3
3  foo1  let2      z  bar1  num2       4
4  foo2  let2      y  bar2  num2       5
5  foo3  let2      x  bar3  num2       6
```

---

So far, I've done this:

```
let = pd.concat( [ df.let1, df.let2 ] )
num = pd.concat( [ df.num1, df.num2 ] )
df = df.drop( ['let1', 'let2', 'num1', 'num2' ], axis=1 )
df = pd.concat( [ df, df ] )    
df[ 'letval' ] = let
df[ 'numval' ] = num
print( df )

    foo   bar letval  numval
0  foo1  bar1      a       1
1  foo2  bar2      b       2
2  foo3  bar3      c       3
0  foo1  bar1      z       4
1  foo2  bar2      y       5
2  foo3  bar3      x       6
```

However, I am pretty sure that there is an easier way to achieve that, without copying to dummy variables and such workarounds.

Any ideas?

Comment: The part you have done can be simplified to `pd.lreshape(df, {'letval': ['let1', 'let2'], 'numval': ['num1', 'num2']})`. It is not a well-documented function so adding it as a comment.

Comment: @ayhan, it's a perfect solution - put it as an answer

Comment: @MaxU Unfortunately it's just a partial solution that Luis already did. It loses the let and num indicator columns.

Comment: @ayhan @MaxU Yes, I need the column names (or whatever label) as additional column to track back... But didn't know about `lreshape`, definitely a good point to look. I also think it's worth to post as partial answer :)

Comment: @Luis Leaving it unanswered increases your chance of getting a full answer so it might be better to wait. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my attempt to combine [@ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543026/stack-two-columns-in-a-dataframe-repeat-others/38543214#comment64478268_38543026)'s solution with the [pd.melt()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html) method:

```
In [191]: (pd.melt(df.drop(['num1','num2'], 1), id_vars=['foo','bar'],
   .....:          var_name='let', value_name='letval')
   .....:    .assign(numval=pd.lreshape(df.filter(like='num'),
   .....:                               {'numval': ['num1', 'num2']})))
Out[191]:
    foo   bar   let letval  numval
0  foo1  bar1  let1      a       1
1  foo2  bar2  let1      b       2
2  foo3  bar3  let1      c       3
3  foo1  bar1  let2      z       4
4  foo2  bar2  let2      y       5
5  foo3  bar3  let2      x       6
```

Comment: If I understand correctly: You first take only 1 `value`  column, by dropping all others, apply `melt` and then put all dropped columns there again (`reshape`+`assign`)... I guess melt only let you do that once, right? I mean, you have only 1 *measurement* (`let`)...

Comment: Still trying to assimilate it. I think I can get to like `melt` (never used it before) ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the meantime, I came out with an answer as well.

Far more modest than [@MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38543214/776515)'s, and based on [@ayhan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543026/stack-two-columns-in-a-dataframe-repeat-others/38543214#comment64478268_38543026)'s comment as well.

```
let = [ 'let1', 'let2' ]
num = [ 'num1', 'num2' ]

n = df.shape[0]
df = pd.lreshape(df, { 'letval': let, 'numval': num } )

df[ 'let' ] = [ item for item in let for _ in range(n) ]
df[ 'num' ] = [ item for item in num for _ in range(n) ]

print( df )


    bar   foo letval  numval   let   num
0  bar1  foo1      a       1  let1  num1
1  bar2  foo2      b       2  let1  num1
2  bar3  foo3      c       3  let1  num1
3  bar1  foo1      z       4  let2  num2
4  bar2  foo2      y       5  let2  num2
5  bar3  foo3      x       6  let2  num2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dfm =  pd.melt(df.drop(['num1','num2'], 1), id_vars=['foo','bar'], var_name=('let'), value_name=('letval'))
dfm[['num', 'numvals']] = pd.melt(df.drop(['let1','let2'], 1), id_vars=['foo','bar'], var_name=('num'), value_name=('numvals'))[['num', 'numvals']]

dfm:
   foo   bar   let  letval  num  numvals
0  foo1  bar1  let1      a  num1        1
1  foo2  bar2  let1      b  num1        2
2  foo3  bar3  let1      c  num1        3
3  foo1  bar1  let2      z  num2        4
4  foo2  bar2  let2      y  num2        5
5  foo3  bar3  let2      x  num2        6
```