# Merge DataFrames on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

This is a follow-up from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38543026/stack-two-columns-in-a-dataframe-repeat-others/38543214)

I have two pandas DataFrames, as follows:

```
print( a )

    foo   bar   let letval
9  foo1  bar1  let1      a
8  foo2  bar2  let1      b
7  foo3  bar3  let1      c
6  foo1  bar1  let2      z
5  foo2  bar2  let2      y
4  foo3  bar3  let2      x

print( b )

    foo   bar   num  numval
0  foo1  bar1  num1       1
1  foo2  bar2  num1       2
2  foo3  bar3  num1       3
3  foo1  bar1  num2       4
4  foo2  bar2  num2       5
5  foo3  bar3  num2       6
```

I want to `merge` the two of them on the columns `[ 'foo', 'bar' ]`.

If I simply do `c = pd.merge( a, b, on=['foo', 'bar'] )`, I get:

```
prnint( c )

     foo   bar   let letval   num  numval
0   foo1  bar1  let1      a  num1       1
1   foo1  bar1  let1      a  num2       4
2   foo1  bar1  let2      z  num1       1
3   foo1  bar1  let2      z  num2       4
4   foo2  bar2  let1      b  num1       2
5   foo2  bar2  let1      b  num2       5
6   foo2  bar2  let2      y  num1       2
7   foo2  bar2  let2      y  num2       5
8   foo3  bar3  let1      c  num1       3
9   foo3  bar3  let1      c  num2       6
10  foo3  bar3  let2      x  num1       3
11  foo3  bar3  let2      x  num2       6
```

I would like:

```
print( c )

    foo   bar   let letval   num   numval
0  foo1  bar1  let1      a   num1       1
1  foo2  bar2  let1      b   num1       2
2  foo3  bar3  let1      c   num1       3
3  foo1  bar1  let2      z   num2       4
4  foo2  bar2  let2      y   num2       5
5  foo3  bar3  let2      x   num2       6
```

The closest I've got is:

```
c = pd.merge( a, b, left_index=['foo', 'bar'], right_index=['foo', 'bar'] )
```

What am I missing?

And why do I get `c.shape = (12,6)` in the first example?

---

**Edit**

Thanks to [@piRSquared's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38547935/776515) I realized that the underlying problem is that there is not a single combination of columns to do that. Thus the merge problem, as posed before cannot be univocally solved. That said, the question is converted into a simpler one:

**How to make a univocal relationship between the tables?**

I solved that with a dictionary that maps the *desired* outputs that need to be aligned:

```
map_ab = { 'num1':'let1', 'num2':'let2' }
b['let'] = b.apply( lambda x: map_ab[x['num']], axis=1 )
c = pd.merge( a, b, on=['foo', 'bar', 'let'] )
print( c )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting that is because the columns you are merging on do not constitute unique combinations.  For example, The first (index 0) row of `a` has `foo1` and `bar1`, but so does the fourth row (index 3).  Ok, that's fine, but `b` has the same issue.  So, when you match up `b`'s `foo1` & `bar1` for row indexed with `0` it matches twice.  Same is true when you match `foo1` & `bar1` in row indexed with `3`, it matches twice.  So you end up with four matches for those 2 rows.

So you get

- `a` row 0 matches with `b` row 0
- `a` row 0 matches with `b` row 3
- `a` row 3 matches with `b` row 0
- `a` row 3 matches with `b` row 3

And THEN, your example does this 2 more times.  `3 * 4 == 12`

The only way to do this and be unambiguous is to decide on a rule on which match to take if there are more than one matches.  I decided to groupby one of your other columns then take the first one.  It still doesn't match your expected output but I'm proposing that you gave a bad example.

```
pd.merge( a, b, on=['foo', 'bar']).groupby(['foo', 'bar', 'let'], as_index=False).first()
```

[image]

Comment: Great explanation on what is happening, specially *when you match up b's foo1 & bar1 for row indexed with 0 it matches twice.* !

Comment: The example is just as good/bad as the problem I have at hand. Admittedly, I did something different (imported the DataFrames differently from files), but it is a situation that happens every now and then.

Comment: @Luis agreed.  But that is the problem.  Given the information you provided, there isn't an unambiguous way to provide an answer.  I could have dropped duplicates, but that wouldn't give the answer you asked for.  Something is wrong with either the data, or the request.  You'll need to reconcile and ask again.

Comment: I see your point with the problem being ambiguous, I've being fooled by the fact that I *know* that a value `let1` must correspond to a value `num1`, both are **1** after all :P I will try to find a better example or change the wording to reflect this.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [combine_first](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
In[21]:a.combine_first(b)
Out[21]: 
    bar   foo   let letval   num  numval
0  bar1  foo1  let1      a  num1       1
1  bar2  foo2  let1      b  num1       2
2  bar3  foo3  let1      c  num1       3
3  bar1  foo1  let2      z  num2       4
4  bar2  foo2  let2      y  num2       5
5  bar3  foo3  let2      x  num2       6
```

In the first example you are doing `inner join` which returns all rows if `bar` & `foo` are equal in `a,b`.

Comment: `combine_first` is matching on `index` and `columns`.  It will produce a dataframe that has an index that is `a.index.union(b.index)` and like wise for the columns.  if you have `a = pd.DataFrame([], list('ab'), list('AB'))` and 
`b = pd.DataFrame([], list('cd'), list('CD'))` then `a.combine_first(b)` will be a 4x4 dataframe.  The point is, your answer is ignoring the fact that the OP wants to join on `['bar', 'foo']` and is actually matching on the given integer index.

Comment: Yes, combine_first work only because the indexes match. If you do `a.index= [ 9,8,7,6,5,4 ] 
a.combine_first(b)` it won't work anymore. Also, the behaviour on `merge` occurs with every option to join (`inner`,`outer`, etc.)